# HashMap output issue

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to use a HashMap to do a project where I read in a list of jumbled words and a file of actual dictionary words and use a HashMap to find all the words that match in the jumbled words file and print them out. The issue is that I cannot get it to print the correct dictionary form of the words, just a canonical version (letters arranged in alphabetical order).

```
public class Jumbles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length < 2 ) die

        BufferedReader dictionaryFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ));
        BufferedReader jumbleFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ));

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> jumbleWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dictionaryWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        while(jumbleFile.ready())
        {
            String word = jumbleFile.readLine();
            String canWord = toCanonical(word); 
            jumbleWords.add(word); 
            map.put(canWord, new ArrayList<String>()); 
        }
        Collections.sort(jumbleWords); 

        while(dictionaryFile.ready())
        {
            String dictWord = dictionaryFile.readLine(); 
            dictionaryWords.add(dictWord); 
        }
        for(String dictionaryWord : dictionaryWords)
        {
            String canDictWord = toCanonical(dictionaryWord); 
            if(map.containsValue(canDictWord))
            {
                ArrayList<String> listOfWords = map.get(canDictWord); 
                listOfWords.add(dictionaryWord);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keysList);
        for(String key : keysList)
        {
            System.out.print(key); 

            ArrayList<String> list = map.get(key);
            Collections.sort(list);
            for(String word : list)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + word);   
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    } 

    private static void die( String errmsg )
    {
        System.out.println( "\nFATAL ERROR: " + errmsg + "\n" );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String toCanonical( String word )
    {
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(letters);
        return new String(letters);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused between keys and values. The code starts by putting canonical words as keys in the map, and lists as values. Then it calls containsValue() with a String as argument. That will always return false.

Comment: So what about putting the dictionary words in as keys in the map instead?

Comment: Are you unscrambling the jumbled words and determining if they are in your dictionary?

Comment: Yes and then printing them out

Comment: Do you need to know if a scrambled word can be unscrambled into more than one word?  Or does the first find works?  Taste, for example, can be unscrambled to state or teats.